# SQL - Rename one column based on values from other columns

Tags: sql, duplicates, amazon-redshift, rename

Let's say we're looking at the date of departure of a bus from the following cities:

| City | Departure_Date | Truck Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Berlin | 2022-05-01 | 001 |
| London | 2022-05-22 | 020 |
| Berlin | 2022-05-22 | 030 |
| London | 2022-05-08 | 090 |

I need to rename the column 'City' if the departure_date is the same. This should be my output:

| City | Departure_Date | Truck Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Berlin | 2022-05-01 | 001 |
| Central | 2022-05-22 | 020 |
| Central | 2022-05-22 | 030 |
| London | 2022-05-08 | 090 |

In this case we rename London and Berlin for 'Central' when they have the same departure_date

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
update t set t.City = 'Central'
from dbo.yourTable t
where exists (
  select
    1
  from dbo.yourTable tt 
  where tt.Departure_Date = t.Departure_Date
    and tt.id != t.id
  )
```